# creating a variable extracting it from for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to extract the variable from this cycle

```
for (igene in gene_name){     
  length(unique(select(filter(df,genes==igene),transcripts)))
}
```

Any helps?

Comment: What is "the variable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
collector <- vector()
i <- 1
for (igene in gene_name){     
  collector[[i]] <- length(unique(select(filter(df,genes==igene),transcripts)))
i <-i +1
}
```

Very ugly put functionally should work.